# C# - How to set the property to Ui Thread

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm getting an error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)). 
What should be the problem here, my senior dev said I need to set it to the UI Thread, here's my code:

```
private bool CanPrintReceipt() {
    return _receipt != null && !IsBusy;
}

private async void PrintReceipt() {
    IsBusy = true;
    try {
        await _printReceiptInteractor.PrintTerminalReceiptAsync(_receipt).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => {
            this.Close();
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.Error($"{nameof(PrintReceipt)}: ", e);
        await this._dialogService
            .ShowMessageOKAsync(e.Message, "Printer Error");
    } finally {
        IsBusy = false; // but when i set this to true , no error
    }
}
```

I'm having error in my other class,

```
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            return;

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); //here it shows that error
    }
```

What do you guys think the problem is? There is no RunAsync, I saw that's the other solution
Thanks,
Nico

Comment: Did you not just ask this question?

Comment: Yep, and removed it after http://stackoverflow.com/q/38759257/251311

Comment: what? , i really dont get the codebase yet

Comment: Btw, why do you have `.ConfigureAwait(false)` here?

Comment: oh yes , cause that is marked as duplicate

Comment: im sorry , bu i really dont know , i just make that a try catch statement. btw that method print the receipt

Comment: So you don't know why you added a method call?

Comment: i removed that , and im not getting any error , lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update UI from thread in WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540260/update-ui-from-thread-in-winrt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

What it does is sets `continueOnCapturedContext` to `false`, which means it not necessary will be the same thread to continue evaluate the function after `awit` that invoked the asynchronous function.

So in your case you don't need it, because that's exactly what you need - to restore in the same thread after it's done.

And in general, the simple rule of thumb is:

- You use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in the library code that is general purpose and does not deal with UIs
- You don't use it otherwise.

Details: [MSDN - Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: thanks , btw already fixed it , and yeah its because of the ConfigureAwait